# How can I extract dates from a string inside a query?

Tags: google-sheets, type-conversion, google-sheets-formula

I am a baseball coach and use a sensor to measure our player's bat speed (mph) among other things. The sensor creates a report where each swing is labeled with a date & time (Apr 04, 2022 06:12:15 pm). I'm able to find the overall average and max across dates. What I'm struggling to do is find the average of each specific day due to the fact that each swing includes the time.

Here's the Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fMzsi5dq0EYh7MJqYLIQnlp_7KJk1LeE/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106268317591050688951&rtpof=true&sd=true

Where I'm struggling is in the 'Individual Players' tab. I'd like to use the drop down in cell B2 to choose a player. I'm able to pull all data (cells A-D) and overall average. Where I'm struggling is **cell F12**. It's not finding the average by day because the dates also include the time. Therefore, it's showing each individual result. The end goal of this section would be to show growth over time as well as averages of each session.

Here's the current formula:

```
=QUERY(A:D,"select A, avg(C), max(C), avg(D) group by A label A 'Avg By Date', avg(C) 'Avg Bat Speed', max(C) 'Peak Bat Speed', avg(D) 'Avg Attack Angle' format avg(C) '##.0', avg(D) '##.0'")
```

I tried using `=left(A7, LEN(A7)-12)`. It works on individual cells, but I can't get it to work as part of the query.

Note that my ultimate goal is to be able to chart growth. This means I need the results of the query to sort by date rather than alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the result you desire:

```
=QUERY(FILTER({DATEVALUE(A4:A),C4:D},A4:A<>""),"select Col1, avg(Col2), max(Col2), avg(Col3) group by Col1 order by Col1 label Col1 'Avg By Date', avg(Col2) 'Avg Bat Speed', max(Col2) 'Peak Bat Speed', avg(Col3) 'Avg Attack Angle' format avg(Col2) '##.0', avg(Col3) '##.0'")
```

### Explanation

The second argument of the `QUERY` is identical to what you already had, save for the fact that I replaced references to column titles (A, C, D) with references to generic column numbers (Col1, Col2, Col3). This is because once a range is passed through `FILTER` (used here to exclude blank rows from the output), Sheets no longer recognizes the lettered column titles any more.

Rather than using `=LEFT(A7, LEN(A7)-12)` to extract the date from column A, I've instead used `DATEVALUE`, which converts a text string into a date, provided the string matches one of the supported formats (which your data does).

Note that when you use this formula in cell F12, it will initially format the dates as plain numbers. This is because, under the hood, Google Sheets stores all dates and times as numbers. To format as a date, use the menu options `Format->Number->Date`. To format identically to your source data, use the menu options `Format->Number->Custom date and time` and select the options you prefer.

Functions used:

- [DATEVALUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093039?hl=en)
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Comment: Wow, thank you @sebastian! I'm new to anything beyond a basic functions and haven't learned regexextract or worked with FIlter yet. I really appreciate your help. I did get around the issue by creating a hidden column (in A) and using this formula: =arrayformula(datevalue(if(isblank(B3:B),"",left(B3:B, LEN(B3:B)-12)))). This also helped by turning column A into a date format. Is there a way to add the datevalue function to the formula you provided? I tried to add it a few places and I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @JimMcMahon I have updated my answer to match your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the update and new info, @sebastian. However, it's still placing July instead of June in F15-F20, even with the changes to the format.

Comment: @JimMcMahon Perhaps I do not understand correctly. I thought that was desired behaviour. Your dataset contains values for July 5th, 6th, 19th, 20th, and 24th, and therefore, the formula has dates for July in cells `F15:F20`. What my update does is put the June date in `F14` which precedes the July dates in `F15:F20`, ordering by date as I had understood.